# Use of [list a b c] vs {a b c} when creating a list

Tags: tcl

What differences are there between creating a list in TCL using:

```
[list a b c]
```

vs

```
{a b c}
```

I'm by all means not an experienced TCL programmer, but the only difference I have encountered so far is when creating a list of multiple lines the first style requires using line continuation characters like:

```
[list \
    a \
    b \
    c \
]
```

where this parses fine:

```
{
    a
    b
    c
}
```

Are there any other differences? Which is considered better style or idiomatic?

It would appear that when creating a complex list with nested lists, the 2nd style is the only clean way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference is that using the `list` command makes it possible to use variables when defining the list. Notice the difference between these two:

```
% set foo 1
1
% set bar 2
2
% set list1 [list $foo $bar]
1 2
% set list2 {$foo $bar}
$foo $bar
```

Note that you can also use double quotes if you want:

```
% set list3 "$foo $bar"
1 2
```

It's important to note that of the two ways to build a list with variables, only using `list` is guaranteed to give you a proper list. Using quotes may or may not give you a list, depending on the contents of the variables. This isn't because Tcl is mysterious or random or buggy -- it's simply how tcl quoting works. With `list` you are asking tcl to construct a list with specific elements, in the others you're creating a string that looks like a list, but whether it can be treated like a list or not depends on the data in the string.

Here's an example where using quotes won't give you a list:

```
% set foo "{"
{
% set list4 "$foo $bar"
{ 2
% lindex $list4 0
unmatched open brace in list
```

... whereas using list will give you a proper list:

```
% set list5 [list $foo $bar]
\{ 2
% lindex $list5 0
{
```

It's important to know that the backslash appears only when tcl converts the list to a string for the purposes of printing the list -- the backslash isn't in the data, as you can see when you use `lindex` to fetch the value.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any other differences? Which is considered better style or idiomatic?

In the case where you're after a list with just literals in it, no variable or command expansion or anything like that, using `[list a b c]` and `{a b c}` is **exactly the same**. They compile to identical bytecode in Tcl 8.6 (the push of a literal onto the result stack). There really is no difference at all.

Which is more idiomatic? I don't really know, to be honest. They are *both* idiomatic, and subject to individual preferences. The difference between them becomes important once you start using variable and command expansion, and then the question quickly ceases to be relevant.

That said, I mostly prefer to use `{a b c}`. It's more convenient when the literals are longer since I can break things over multiple lines without fussing around with backslash continuations. Other people will disagree with me; for them, the typing of `[list`…`]` reminds them strongly of what they intend to do with the data, and that's clearly of some mnemonic value.